# Tensorflow: Label inception has no images in the category training

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am retraining the Inception v3 network based on the code here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0.
I have a set of 200 labels. Each label has images with their count ranging from 50 to 15000. While retraining I get the following error:

```
2017-01-08 07:42:09.683263: Step 30: Train accuracy = 6.0%
2017-01-08 07:42:09.683384: Step 30: Cross entropy = 6.297137
2017-01-08 07:42:09.808175: Step 30: Validation accuracy = 0.0%
2017-01-08 07:42:11.083850: Step 40: Train accuracy = 2.0%
2017-01-08 07:42:11.083964: Step 40: Cross entropy = 6.296147
CRITICAL:tensorflow:Label corset has no images in the category validation.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 1012, in <module>
   tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run
   sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
 File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 839, in main
   bottleneck_tensor))
 File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 480, in get_random_cached_bottlenecks
   bottleneck_tensor)
 File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 388, in get_or_create_bottleneck
   bottleneck_dir, category)
 File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 245, in get_bottleneck_path
   category) + '.txt'
 File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 221, in get_image_path
   mod_index = index % len(category_list)
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero`
```

Search on google has made me understand that such errors can happen if images are less than 20. This can happen because their may not be sufficient images left for validation. However I have at least 50 images. So why am I sill getting this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at the `tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py` file which is linked from the tutorial in your post.

Part of the code that runs is a train/validation split that takes place in the function `create_image_lists(image_dir, testing_percentage, validation_percentage)`

The default value for the split is 10% and it's stated in the `FLAGS.validation_percentage`

Since you have classes that have less than 200 images, the split return classes with less than 20 photos for validation and that's where the error you are getting occur.

Try to run the code with only the classes with more than 200 images and see if it helps. if it does you can consider adding more images or manipulate the create_image_lists function to return at least 20 photos for validation.

Comment: Yes it worked. I added more images to the classes that have less than 200 images and brought the final count above 200.